# How to generate task in sequential workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin

I have created sequential workflow in visual studio now i want to generate task one by one.

for ex. first generate one task, on complete this task generate another task for another user.

i want to generate task like publishing approval workflow. if in workflow association from three user selected then generate task parallel and in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

For a single user use the **Assign a Task** action for multiple users use the **Start a Task Process** action.

As long as you check the box for `Wait for task completion` then your workflow will wait until the task has been completed. You've got a couple more options with the multiple users but it essentially works the same. So you can just line the tasks up one after another for a sequential workflow. You can always add parallel tasks after these as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In declarative workflows (Visual Studio) the equivalent tasks are located under *SP - Task* in the toolbox and are **CompositeTask** (Multiple users, same as *Start a Task Process* above) and **SingleTask** (Single user, same as *Assign a Task* above). The property you are looking for is `WaitForTaskCompletion = True`

Comment: i want to do it in visual studio and there isn't option for Start a Task Process.

Comment: I've added the equivalent action names above.